# Weird output when running Java, C++ or other language script (except Python) in VSCode

Tags: c++, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, conda, workspace

Basically, the anaconda activates even if this is a c++ script and not a python one.
(Please see the output in the attached image)

Output : **c:\Projects\C++ - Projects>conda activate tf**
[as you can see the cout runs without taking any input due to this][1]

This is just a little annoying for me.
Please see if there is any solution to this , my guess is there is some workspace settings in vscode that is causing this.
Thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swapping(int &a, int &b)
{ //swap the content of a and b
   int temp;
   temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
void display(int *array, int size)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      cout << array[i] << " ";
   cout << endl;
}
void bubbleSort(int *array, int size)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      int swaps = 0; //flag to detect any swap is there or not
      for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
      {
         if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
         { //when the current item is bigger than next
            swapping(array[j], array[j + 1]);
            swaps = 1; //set swap flag
         }
      }
      if (!swaps)
         break; // No swap in this pass, so array is sorted
   }
}
int main()
{
   int n;
   cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
   cin >> n;
   int arr[n]; //create an array with given number of elements
   cout << "Enter elements:" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      cin >> arr[i];
   }
   cout << "Array before Sorting: ";
   display(arr, n);
   bubbleSort(arr, n);
   cout << "Array after Sorting: ";
   display(arr, n);
}
```

EDIT - Basically code exits after running without taking any input.
Now my vsode terminal outputs following :-

```
C:\Projects>cd "c:\Projects\C++ - Projects\" && g++ bubblesort.cpp -o bubblesort && "c:\Projects\C++ - Projects\"bubblesort
Enter the number of elements: gggcd "c:\Projects\C++ - Projects\" && g++ bubblesort.cpp -o bubblesort && "c:\Projects\C++ - Projects\"bubblesort
Enter elements:
Array before Sorting:
Array after Sorting:

c:\Projects\C++ - Projects>
```

Comment: Include your code _as text_, not an image. This sounds like a classic case of using getline or reading a string after entering a number, but we can't tell without your code.

Comment: Please, don't post source code as screenshots. Use the "Code Sample" button in the editor. Describe the behavour, the expected behaviour and what jou tried. Try  also to get a better title.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i have edited the question , hope now it's in good format.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle okay thanks for the heads up , i have edited my question now as that was my first ever asked question.

Comment: You could work around your problem by making your code defensive against wrong input. But the problem is that you do have wrong input, which is most likely caused by the environment setup. Please show all relevant configurations, including but not only the content of your workspace settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help